# Wave on a string- Reflection of waves

Tags: waves, reflection, string

A pulse is sent on a string which is attached to a ring at the right end, and the ring is free to move without friction on a vertical rod. When the pulse reaches the ring, the ring is displaced upwards due to this wave and reaches a height of $2A$ (where $A$ is amplitude of original wave)
But, the reflected wave has an amplitude equal to that of original wave ($A$), even though the ring moves up by a distance more than original amplitude, why dosent the reflected wave start from the maximum displacement of the ring and reflect back with a greater amplitude than original wave?

Please explain in non highly mathematical terms.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't know that I can explain the amplitude of the reflected wave, but it should be obvious because of conservation of energy that it cannot be greater than the amplitude than the incident wave.

Comment: Yes, but wanted an explanation without energy conservation about what happens with ring.

Answer (score 2):

That would require making energy. The string ahead of the wave acts like a load who's impedance is perfectly matched, so the energy is continually absorbed and transferred to the next bit of string. If there was a perfectly matched load, it would absorb the energy and the wave would stop, but when it reaches the ring, which is effectively an open circuit, there is suddenly no load, so the string overshoots to double the height, effectively pulling up on the string, transferring the energy back and sending a wave (reflecting the wave) with the same amplitude and phase back. If the ring was fixed, the string would swing across like a guitar string, transferring the energy back as a negative phase wave.